# Unable to logon locally to a newly created account

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm running windows 2008, and just created a new user that belongs to `Users` group, and I checked the `Allow logon locally` gpo, `Users` was there

While the password is correct, I couldn't just logon, it kept telling me that user or password is incorrect, but administrator works.

[image]

As in the picture, the account is Active.

Anyone got a hint on this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to refresh policy *Command Prompt* > ***gpupdate /force*** and try again?
Seems like changes have not been applied.

Comment: I dont think so...that's the default setting so no update needed, am I wrong?

Comment: The policy will be updated automatically according to refresh policy interval. If you want changes to group policy to be applied immediately, then gpupdate should be used. But, actually, if policy was not updated, it would have told that no local logon allowed..